# progress bar in jupyter notebook go crazy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, moviepy

I once tried to run the code as what in the following picture. The first time everything work right, it has only **one** progress bar. But when I run it again(to produce a video), the progress bar just go crazy as following, it generate many progress bars for the single task per second! How can I make it to just generate **SINGLE** progress bar. Thank you!

Here is what I'm facing:
[image]

Comment: Please add image in the question itself. Third party sites may be blocked or not accessible.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1527/

Comment: Yeah, I too would like to know if there is a way to prevent this. All the similar questions I can find ask how to make a progress bar that works in Jupyter, not how to deal with ones which don't work because they rely on carriage returns. There is plenty of code which already implements progress bars for the terminal which people just need to use, and which they cannot simply "fix" to work with Jupyter. There needs to be something that one can do on the Jupyter side to somehow deal with this kind of attempted output. Can one do something like capture the print output and modify it?

Comment: You can always ignore the stdout of those programs/functions.

Comment: You can use `progress_bar=False` in `write_videofile` to ignore it altogether. BTW, have fun with the SDC nanodegree.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to excellent `tqdm` library and because all libraries use the classic tqdm instead of the notebook version.

What I do now for all notebook is to import and alias the version for notebook:

```
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
```

Links:

- https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/#ipython-jupyter-integration

Comment: it should yes (it works in my case, with https://github.com/zalandoresearch/flair).

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but to at least avoid the crazy cell output you can use the `%%capture` cell magic command to suppress output for that cell. You won't see any progress, but that might be preferable to mountains of output that Jupyter fails to render as the programmer expected.

See also http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-capture